# Making a grouped bar chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I'm new to d3.js and I'm finding hard to create grouped bar chart but I tried something which appears to be not right. I want months in x-axis and count of group(mars and jupiter) in y-axis. something like dis [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VowEA.png).

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right, height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0,
width]).padding(0.1),
  y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [
        {"Group":"Mars","count":10,"months":"June"},
        {"Group":"Jupiter","count":50,"months":"June"},
 {"Group":"Mars","count":70,"months":"July"},
        {"Group":"Jupiter","count":60,"months":"July"}];


     var ymaxdomain=d3.max(d,function(d){return d.count;});
     x.domain(d.map(function(d) {return d.months}));
    y.domain([0,ymaxdomain]);

   
  
   var x1=d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, x.bandwidth()]);
         x1.domain(d.map(function(d) {return d.months;}));

   

    g.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d,i) {console.log(d,i); return (x(d.months))}
        .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.count); })
        .attr("width",x1.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.count); })
    
  g.append("g")
   .attr("class", "axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(d3.axisBottom(x));


  g.append("g")
   .attr("class", "axis")
   .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
   .append("text")
   .attr("x", 2)
   .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
   .attr("dy", "0.32em")
   .attr("fill", "#000")
   .attr("font-weight", "bold")
   .attr("text-anchor", "start")
   .text("count");
```

```css
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke:black
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg width="600" height="600"></svg>
<body><script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script></body>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For creating a grouped bar chart, you have to set 2 scales for the x position:

```
var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width])
  .padding(0.1);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([0, x.bandwidth()])
  .padding(0.05);
```

Then, you append groups using the first scale...

```
var groups = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.months) + ",0)";
  })
```

... and, inside each group, you append the rects using the second scale.

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width])
  .padding(0.1),
  y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{
  "Group": "Mars",
  "count": 10,
  "months": "June"
}, {
  "Group": "Jupiter",
  "count": 50,
  "months": "June"
}, {
  "Group": "Mars",
  "count": 70,
  "months": "July"
}, {
  "Group": "Jupiter",
  "count": 60,
  "months": "July"
}];

var ymaxdomain = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.count;
});
x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.months
}));
y.domain([0, ymaxdomain]);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([0, x.bandwidth()])
  .padding(0.05)
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.Group;
  }));

color.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.Group;
}));

var groups = g.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.months) + ",0)";
  })

var bars = groups.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d]
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return x1(d.Group)
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.count);
  })
  .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.count);
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.Group)
  })

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", 2)
  .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
  .attr("dy", "0.32em")
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .text("count");
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke: black
}
```

```html
<svg width="600" height="600"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I cant thank you enough for your help. Thankyou so much!:)@Gerardo Furtado

Comment: I am learning d3js .... Here you call the function x and pass an arg d.months... Where are you using it in var x = .....