# d3.js : Selector dropdown in grouped bar chart select wrong graph

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, d3.js

I have a problem with my dropdown. My dropdown selected the wrong graphic. Supposedly when the up dropdown selects the year then the up graph is affected, but the result is the down graph is the one affected. This is my code:

```js
// the first graph
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 850 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 370 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var legendRectSize = 18;
var legendSpacing = 4;

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width])
  .padding(0.1),
  y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select("#graph")
  .append("svg")
  .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + "px")
  .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + "px")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .attr("class", "svg");

var data = [{
  "level": "SMP",
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Jan",
  "value": "3"
}, {
  "level": "SMA",
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Jan",
  "value": "6"
}, {
  "level": "SMA",
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Feb",
  "value": "9"
}, {
  "level": "SMP",
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Feb",
  "value": "7"
}, {
  "level": "SMA",
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Mar",
  "value": "8"
}, {
  "level": "SMP",
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Mar",
  "value": "9"
}, {
  "level": "SMA",
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Apr",
  "value": "4"
}, {
  "level": "SMP",
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Apr",
  "value": "13"
}, {
  "level": "SMA",
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "May",
  "value": "5"
}, {
  "level": "SMP",
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "May",
  "value": "6"
}, {
  "level": "SMP",
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Jun",
  "value": "10"
}, {
  "level": "SMA",
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Jun",
  "value": "7"
}, {
  "level": "SMP",
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Jul",
  "value": "11"
}, {
  "level": "SMA",
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Jul",
  "value": "9"
}, {
  "level": "SMP",
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Aug",
  "value": "4"
}, {
  "level": "SMA",
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Aug",
  "value": "9"
}, {
  "level": "SMP",
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Sep",
  "value": "19"
}, {
  "level": "SMA",
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Sep",
  "value": "7"
}, {
  "level": "SMA",
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Oct",
  "value": "5"
}, {
  "level": "SMP",
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Oct",
  "value": "8"
}, {
  "level": "SMA",
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Nov",
  "value": "11"
}, {
  "level": "SMP",
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Nov",
  "value": "14"
}, {
  "level": "SMA",
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Dec",
  "value": "7"
}, {
  "level": "SMP",
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Dec",
  "value": "9"
}];

var nest = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.year;
  })
  .entries(data)


var ymaxdomain = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.value;
});

console.log(ymaxdomain)

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.month
}));
y.domain([0, ymaxdomain]);

console.log("data:", data);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([0, x.bandwidth()])
  .padding(0.05)
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.level;
  }));
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
color.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.level;
}));

var yearSelect = d3.select("#Dropdown")

yearSelect
  .append("select")
  .selectAll("option")
  .data(nest)
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .attr("value", function(d) {
    return d.key;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  });

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    console.log(d)
    d3.select(".d3-tip").style("background-color", d.color);
    return "<strong>Level : </strong>" + d.level + "<br><strong>Jumlah : </strong>" + d.value + " siswa";
  });

svg.call(tip);

var initialGraph = function(year) {

  // Filter the data to include only year of interest
  var selectYear = nest.filter(function(d) {
    return d.key == year;
  })

  var selectYearGroups = svg.selectAll(".yearGroups")
    .data(selectYear, function(d) {
      return d ? d.key : this.key;
    })
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "yearGroups")

  var groups = selectYearGroups.selectAll("group")
    .data(function(d) {
      return d.values;
    })
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + x(d.month) + ",0)";
    });

  var bars = groups.selectAll("bar")
    .data(function(d) {
      return [d]
    })
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return x1(d.level)
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return d.color = color(d.level)
    })
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

}
var c = "2021";
console.log(c)
initialGraph(c)

var updateGraph = function(year) {
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
  color.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.level;
  }));
  // Filter the data to include only fruit of interest
  var selectYear = nest.filter(function(d) {
    return d.key == year;
  })
  // Select all of the grouped elements and update the data
  var selectYearGroups = svg.selectAll(".yearGroups")
    .data(selectYear)

  // Select all the lines and transition to new positions
  d3.select('#graph').selectAll('rect').remove();
  var groups = selectYearGroups.selectAll("group")
    .data(function(d) {
      return d.values;
    })
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + x(d.month) + ",0)";
    })

  var bars = groups.selectAll("bar")
    .data(function(d) {
      return [d]
    });
  bars.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return d.color = color(d.level)
    })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return x1(d.level)
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.value);
    })
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

}

var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
  .data(color.domain()) // NEW
  .enter() // NEW
  .append('g') // NEW
  .attr('class', 'legend') // NEW
  .attr('transform', function(d, i) { // NEW
    var height1 = 15; // NEW
    var offset = 1 * color.domain().length / 2; // NEW
    var horz = 37 * legendRectSize; // NEW
    var vert = i * height1 - offset; // NEW
    return 'translate(' + horz + ',' + vert + ')'; // NEW
  }); // NEW

legend.append('text') // NEW
  .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing) // NEW
  .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)

  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .style('fill', color);

// Run update function when dropdown selection changes
yearSelect.on('change', function() {

  // Find which fruit was selected from the dropdown
  var selectedYear = d3.select(this)
    .select("select")
    .property("value")

  // Run update function with the selected fruit
  updateGraph(selectedYear)

});


svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", 2)
  .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
  .attr("dy", "0.32em")
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .text("Jumlah Siswa");

// the second graph
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 100
  },
  width = 850 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 370 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width])
  .padding(0.1),
  y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select("#graph2")
  .append("svg")
  .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + "px")
  .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + "px")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .attr("class", "svg");

var data2 = [{
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Aug",
  "student": "11",
  "money": "2750000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}, {
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Dec",
  "student": "11",
  "money": "2750000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}, {
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Jul",
  "student": "17",
  "money": "4250000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}, {
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Jun",
  "student": "13",
  "money": "3250000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}, {
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Nov",
  "student": "11",
  "money": "2750000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}, {
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Oct",
  "student": "17",
  "money": "4250000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}, {
  "year": "2020",
  "month": "Sep",
  "student": "9",
  "money": "2250000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}, {
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Apr",
  "student": "15",
  "money": "3750000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}, {
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Aug",
  "student": "13",
  "money": "3250000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}, {
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Feb",
  "student": "5",
  "money": "1250000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}, {
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Jan",
  "student": "17",
  "money": "4250000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}, {
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Jul",
  "student": "8",
  "money": "2000000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}, {
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Jun",
  "student": "13",
  "money": "3250000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}, {
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Mar",
  "student": "11",
  "money": "2750000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}, {
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "May",
  "student": "17",
  "money": "4250000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}, {
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Oct",
  "student": "1",
  "money": "250000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}, {
  "year": "2021",
  "month": "Sep",
  "student": "11",
  "money": "2750000",
  "description": "Biaya Pendaftaran Siswa Baru"
}];

var nest2 = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.year;
  })
  .entries(data2)


var ymaxdomain = d3.max(data2, function(d) {
  return d.money;
});

console.log(ymaxdomain)

x.domain(data2.map(function(d) {
  return d.month
}));
y.domain([0, ymaxdomain]);

console.log("data:", data2);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([0, x.bandwidth()])
  .padding(0.05)
  .domain(data2.map(function(d) {
    return d.description;
  }));

var dollarFormat = function(d) {
  return 'Rp. ' + d3.format(',d')(d)
};

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
color.domain(data2.map(function(d) {
  return d.description;
}));

var yearMenu2 = d3.select("#Dropdown2")

yearMenu2
  .append("select")
  .selectAll("select")
  .data(nest2)
  .enter()
  .append("option")
  .attr("value", function(d) {
    return d.key;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  });

var tip2 = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip2')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    console.log(d)
    d3.select(".d3-tip2").style("background-color", d.color);
    return "<strong>Deskripsi : </strong>" + d.description + "<br><strong>Total Siswa : </strong>" + d.student + " siswa" + "<br><strong>Total Pemasukan: </strong>" + dollarFormat(d.money);
  });

svg.call(tip2);

// Filter the data to include only year of interest
var selectYear = nest2.filter(function(d) {
  return d.key == "2020";
})

var selectYearGroups = svg.selectAll(".yearGroups2")
  .data(selectYear, function(d) {
    return d ? d.key : this.key;
  })
  .enter()

var groups = selectYearGroups.selectAll("group2")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.month) + ",0)";
  });

var bars = groups.selectAll("chart")
  .data(function(d) {
    return [d]
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return x1(d.description)
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.money);
  })
  .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.money);
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return d.color = color(d.description)
  })
  .on('mouseover', tip2.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip2.hide);


var updateGraph = function(year) {
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
  color.domain(data2.map(function(d) {
    return d.description;
  }));
  // Filter the data to include only fruit of interest
  var selectYear2 = nest2.filter(function(d) {
    return d.key == year;
  })
  // Select all of the grouped elements and update the data
  var selectYearGroups2 = svg.selectAll(".yearGroups2")
    .data(selectYear2, function(d) {
      return d ? d.key : this.key;
    })
    .enter()

  // Select all the lines and transition to new positions
  d3.select('#graph2').selectAll('rect').remove();
  var groups2 = selectYearGroups2.selectAll("group2")
    .data(function(d) {
      return d.values;
    })
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + x(d.month) + ",0)";
    })

  var bars = groups2.selectAll("chart")
    .data(function(d) {
      return [d]
    });
  bars.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return d.color = color(d.description)
    })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return x1(d.description)
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.money);
    })
    .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.money);
    })
    .on('mouseover', tip2.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip2.hide);

}

// Run update function when dropdown selection changes
yearMenu2.on('change', function() {

  // Find which fruit was selected from the dropdown
  var selectedYear = d3.select(this)
    .select("select")
    .property("value")

  // Run update function with the selected fruit
  updateGraph(selectedYear)


});

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(dollarFormat))
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", 2)
  .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
  .attr("dy", "0.32em")
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold")
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .text("Total Pemasukan");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3 Page Template</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.7.1/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    /* set the CSS */
    
    .bar {
      fill: steelblue;
      stroke: black
    }
    
    body {
      font: 12px Arial;
    }
    
    path {
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2;
      fill: none;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: grey;
      stroke-width: 1;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    #graph3 {
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    #graph2 {
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    #graph {
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    #legendContainer {
      position: absolute;
      top: 120px;
      left: 10px;
      overflow: auto;
      height: 490px;
      width: 110px;
    }
    
    .d3-tip {
      line-height: 1;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 12px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 2px;
    }
    /* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
    
    .d3-tip:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: inline;
      font-size: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 1;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      content: "\25BC";
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
    }
    /* Style northward tooltips differently */
    
    .d3-tip.n:after {
      margin: -1px 0 0 0;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .d3-tip2 {
      line-height: 1;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 12px;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 2px;
    }
    /* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
    
    .d3-tip2:after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: inline;
      font-size: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 1;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      content: "\25BC";
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
    }
    /* Style northward tooltips differently */
    
    .d3-tip2.n:after {
      margin: -1px 0 0 0;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="Dropdown"></div>
  <div id="graph"></div>
  <div id="tooltip"></div>

  <div id="Dropdown2"></div>
  <div id="graph2"></div>
  <div id="tooltip2"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I made the code by looking at the following link:

1. [grouped bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45213564/16256959)
2. [selector dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178752/16256959)

Comment: You declare `updateGraph` twice - you're only calling it after defining it the second time.